# How to construct a column name when an aggregate function is used on a column using pyparsing library in Python?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am trying parse a SQL query using Python's pyparsing library.
As part of that, I implemented the below code:

```
from pyparsing import *

ParserElement.enablePackrat()

select_stmt = Forward().setName("select statement")

# Define keywords and symbols
SELECT = CaselessKeyword("SELECT")
FROM = CaselessKeyword("FROM")
JOIN = CaselessKeyword("JOIN")
ON = CaselessKeyword("ON")
WHERE = CaselessKeyword("WHERE")
GROUP_BY = CaselessKeyword("GROUP BY")
HAVING = CaselessKeyword("HAVING")
ORDER_BY = CaselessKeyword("ORDER BY")
AS = CaselessKeyword("AS")

COMMA = Suppress(",")
LPAREN = Suppress("(")
RPAREN = Suppress(")")
DOT, STAR = map(Literal, ".*")

# Define SQL language elements
ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars(" \t")
identifier = Regex(r"[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*")
columnName = identifier + ZeroOrMore("." + identifier)
tableName = identifier + ZeroOrMore("." + identifier)
columnNameList = delimitedList(columnName)
tableNameList = delimitedList(tableName)
alias = identifier
aliasExpression = AS + alias
column = columnName + Optional(aliasExpression)

selectStatement = SELECT + columnNameList + FROM + tableNameList + \
                  ZeroOrMore(JOIN + tableName + ON + columnName + "=" + columnName) + \
                  Optional(WHERE + columnName + Regex(r"[><=]") + columnName) + \
                  Optional(GROUP_BY + columnNameList + Optional(HAVING + columnName + Regex(r"[><=]") + Regex(r"[0-9]+"))) + \
                  Optional(ORDER_BY + columnNameList + Optional(CaselessKeyword("ASC") | CaselessKeyword("DESC")))


# Define a function to extract column names and table names from a SQL query
def extract_columns_and_tables(query):
    column_aliases = {}
    table_aliases = {}
    try:
        result = selectStatement.parseString(query)  # fixed variable name
        # Extract column names and aliases
        for col in result[1:]:
            if AS in col:
                col_name, col_alias = col.split(AS)
                column_aliases[col_name.strip()] = col_alias.strip()
            else:
                column_aliases[col.strip()] = col.strip()
        
        # Extract table names and aliases
        for tbl in result[4:]:
            if AS in tbl:
                tbl_name, tbl_alias = tbl.split(AS)
                table_aliases[tbl_name.strip()] = tbl_alias.strip()
            else:
                table_aliases[tbl.strip()] = tbl.strip()
    
    except ParseException as e:
        print("Error: ", e)
    
    return column_aliases, table_aliases


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Test the function with the given SQL query
    query = "SELECT employees.employee_id, employees.first_name, employees.last_name, departments.department_name, AVG(salaries.salary) AS average_salary FROM employees JOIN salaries ON employees.employee_id = salaries.employee_id JOIN dept_emp ON employees.employee_id = dept_emp.employee_id JOIN departments ON dept_emp.dept_no = departments.dept_no WHERE salaries.to_date > NOW() AND dept_emp.to_date > NOW() GROUP BY employees.employee_id, departments.department_name HAVING AVG(salaries.salary) > 50000 ORDER BY average_salary DESC"
    column_aliases, table_aliases = extract_columns_and_tables(query)

    # Print the results
    print("Column aliases: ", column_aliases)
    print("Table aliases: ", table_aliases)
```

All I am trying to do here parse the query and get table names & column names.
But when I run the query I get an error message:

```
Error:  Expected CaselessKeyword 'FROM', found '('  (at char 105), (line:1, col:106)
```

My query doesn't contain any syntactical issues. Also in the selectstatement I created, `SELECT` + `COLUMNS` + `FROM` so I don't understand where did I make a mistake here.

Query I am trying to parse:

```
SELECT employees.employee_id, employees.first_name, employees.last_name, departments.department_name, AVG(salaries.salary) AS average_salary FROM employees JOIN salaries ON employees.employee_id = salaries.employee_id JOIN dept_emp ON employees.employee_id = dept_emp.employee_id JOIN departments ON dept_emp.dept_no = departments.dept_no WHERE salaries.to_date > NOW() AND dept_emp.to_date > NOW() GROUP BY employees.employee_id, departments.department_name HAVING AVG(salaries.salary) > 50000 ORDER BY average_salary DESC
```

Edit1:
The error occurs exactly at the aggregate function: AVG in the select clause when it encounters an open bracket:

```
SELECT employees.employee_id, employees.first_name, employees.last_name, departments.department_name, **AVG(**salaries.salary) AS average_salary FROM
```

Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I made here and how can I correct it?
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There is a SELECT parser in the pyparsing GitHub repo here: https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/master/examples/select_parser.py. I tried it  with your problem SELECT statement and it parses successfully. Please review that example for ways in which it addresses your issue with a builtin function.